# How to access JBoss 5.1 GA 's MBeans?

Tags: jboss, jmx, mbeans

I would like to access JBoss server's mbeans with my POJO class. I learned about mbeans in [these site](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?page_id=655).But I'm not satisfied.Is there any ways to access JBoss server's mbeans with java class and how to apply these mbeans?

Answer (score 1):

To get reference to local JBoss MBean server, the easiest way is to use MBeanServerLocator.  Check this link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowCanIGetAReferenceToTheMBeanServer

If you want access to remote JBoss MBean server, then you can either use:

1. JMXConnectionFactory http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorFactory.html or
2. RMI adaptor http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connecting_to_the_JMX_Server-Connecting_to_JMX_Using_RMI.html

You can find plenty of examples for each approach if you Google it.

Comment: I'm not understand this links.Please share more basic references.

Comment: One more useful (at least for me) link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/FindMBeanServer